Show Table From Drop Down List

Can you look up and show two columns or a table based on a cell's value?
I want to select either group 1 or 2 or 3 from the dropdown in B1. No problem creating the dropdown.
What formula/s should I use to then show the list of people in group 1 with name (col 1) and Planet) in A7
No problem with laying out data differently or creating tables etc. if need be. Additional names will be added to the list at a later stage.

Use FILTER() function.
=DROP(FILTER(E2:L4,SCAN(E1,E1:L1,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,x)))=B1),,-1)



Neat. I did find that I had to extend it to column M to get it to work for group 3 (because you're dropping the last column) =DROP(FILTER(E2:M4,SCAN(E1,E1:M1,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="",a,x)))=B1),,-1)

@TomSharpe Thank you! I couldn't think that. Nice catch.
